# Does EMET auto update itself?

Tags: virus, emet

I cannot see this option and no answer after google for it. May be it is not good to update update itself since it suppose to be customized so if it updates itself would screw up the profile?

Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit
[EMET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2458544)

Answer (score 0):

I read the EMET [user manual](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50802) and found this, which eludes to the fact that you have to manually update EMET to the next version and how to export your setting beforehand.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not update automatically.

As of today, the latest version of the *Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit (EMET)* is v**5.51** which can be downloaded from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53354.
A conversion utility is provided in the download page for previous versions (v5.5 beta and backwards).

The product's end-of-life date is July 31, 2018. More information can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2458544). It was previously scheduled for January 2017, as seen in Moab's screenshot, but it was extended after reaction from the community ([this](https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/cert/2016/11/windows-10-cannot-protect-insecure-applications-like-emet-can.html), in particular).